# Several algebras in conditional and join probabilities

Tags: probability

There are several cases in combining conditional and joint probabilities, I get confused to show them if there are correct:

Given $A, B, C$ are random variables, $P(A|B)$ denotes conditional probability and $P(B, C)$ denotes joint probability.

1. $P((A|B)|C) = P(A|(B, C))$

We have: $P((A|B)|C) = \frac{P((A|B), C)}{P(C)}$. This requires following

2. $P((A|B), C) = P(A|(B, C))P(C)$

If the equality holds, there would be no ambiguity with $P(A|B, C)$

Comment: The notations $(A|B)$ and $(B, C)$ (even this sometimes can be understood as $B\cap C$, but it's better to be more explicit) are not well defined (not events), so it is meaningless to talk about the expression "P((A|B)|C)".

Comment: Oddly enough, this is not the first time the absurd P((A|B)|C) pops up on the site. I remember some exhausting discussions with a user to make them realize the thing was not correct. (On the other hand, P(A|B,C) to mean P(A|B∩C) is standard.)

Comment: @Xingdong Any source for the notation P((A|B)|C)?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for the remark, now the question is updated.

Comment: @XingdongZuo Please correct, or explain the notation $P((A|B)|C)$.

Comment: @Did We are studying a probabilistic robotics course, in the part of recursive Bayes filter, it has to use these, e.g. $p(x_t|z_1, u_1, \dots, z_{t-1}, u_{t-1}, u_t)$ apply law of total probability with a new random variable $x_{t-1}$ to become $\int p(x_t|x_{t-1}, z_1, u_1, \dots, z_{t-1}, u_{t-1}, u_t) p(x_{t-1}|z_1, u_1, \dots, z_{t-1}, u_{t-1}, u_t) dx_{t-1}$

Comment: Unbelievable: switching to random variables instead of events is exactly the rhetorical move the user I mentioned above made. There must be some common source of these misconceptions somewhere, due to some devious author of textbook... OP: Still absurd with random variables, sorry.

Comment: @Zhanxiong The situation is like the comment I just replied to "Did", to simplify, it a conditional probability, e.g. $P(A|B)$ has to be applied with law of total probability with a new random variable $C$, so it becomes $P((A|B), C)$, then expand again to contain $P((A|B)|C)$

Comment: Ah, but this is an entirely different context, involving no P((A|B)|C) at all... Please make up your mind and ask the question you are really interested in.

Comment: @Did But by the definition, we can write $P(A, B) = P(A|B)P(B)$, so here if we replace $A$ as a conditional probability, won't it have this double conditional form ?

Comment: What you seem to be really after is often named *the Bayes formula of total causes*, which says that, for every events $A$ and $B$ and every *partition* $(C_i)$ of the sample space, $$P(A\mid B)=\sum_iP(A\mid B,C_i)P(C_i\mid B).$$

Comment: "if we replace A as a conditional probability" This is the step where the misconception lies. One cannot "replace" an event A by an... object (A|B) (which does not exist anyway, only P(A|B) does).

Comment: @Did Aha, yes. And by the way, since the essential idea of law of total probability, is it in the starting form as $P(A|B) = \sum_i P((A|B), C_i)$

Comment: @Did Okay, it seems there can never be problems without any parenthesis,  since the comma separate only about event. e.g. $P(A|B, C_i)$ can only be understood as "probability event $A$ conditional with both event $B$ and event $C_i$". There doesn't exist explanation as "joint probability of event $C_i$ and $(A|B)$"

Comment: No, once again, **there exists no such thing as an event (A|B)**, hence P((A|B),C) in your previous-to-last comment is absurd and (A|B) in your last comment is absurd.

Comment: @Did Will there be a proof or derivation of the formula above (so-called Bayes formula of total causes, Google does not show result about it). Since I am not sure to use which axioms or identities to prove it

Comment: @XingdongZuo Note $$P(A|B, C_i)P(C_i|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B \cap C_i)}{P(B\cap C_i)}\times \frac{P(C_i\cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C_i)}{P(B)}.$$

Comment: Indeed, and sum this over $i$, using that $(C_i)$ is a partition, hence $$\sum_iP(A,B,C_i)=P(A,B).$$

Answer (score -2):

We can to understand $\Bbb{P}(A \vert B) = \Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B)](\omega)$ for any $\omega \in B$.

In that sense one would interpret $\Bbb{P}((A \vert B) \vert C) = \Bbb{E}\Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B)] \vert \sigma(1_C)](\omega)$ for $\omega \in B \cap C$

$$\Bbb{P}((A \vert B) \vert C) = \Bbb{E}\Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B)] \vert \sigma(1_C)](\omega) = \Bbb{E}\Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B, 1_C)] |\sigma(1_B)] \vert \sigma(1_C)](\omega) = \Bbb{E}\Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B, 1_C)] \vert \sigma(1_C)](\omega) = \Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B, 1_C)](\omega) = P(A \vert B,C)  $$

**Note** $\Bbb{E}[1_A\vert \sigma(1_B)]$ is a random variable 
$$\Bbb{E}[1_A\vert \sigma(1_B)] = P(A\vert B) 1_B + P(A\vert B^c)1_{B^c} $$

The relation we used for conditional expectations was this one.

$$\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow\Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}[1_A |\mathcal{G}] |\mathcal{F}] = \Bbb{E}[\Bbb{E}[1_A |\mathcal{G}]$$

where $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ are sigma algebras.

Note that we are understanding $P(A\vert B,C) = \Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B, 1_C)]$ wich is different than $\Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B 1_C)]$ to finally get a number we write

$$\Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B, 1_C)] = P(A\vert B \cap C)1_{B \cap C} + P(A\vert B^c \cap C)1_{B^c \cap C} + P(A\vert B \cap C^c)1_{B \cap C^c}+ P(A\vert B^c \cap C^c)1_{B^c \cap C^c}$$

So you define $P(A \vert B,C) = \Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B, 1_C)] (\omega)$  for any $\omega \in B \cap C$

As you would have defined $P(A\vert B) = \Bbb{E}[1_A |\sigma(1_B)](\omega)$ for any $\omega \in B$

Comment: Sorry but $P(A\mid B)$ and $E(1_A\mid\sigma(B))$ are two different objects since the former is a real number which is the value of the latter (a random variable) on the event $B$. Thus the first sentence of your post (contradicted by the note) is not true.

Comment: The line of computations just before the note is wrong as well (there is no reason why $P(A\mid\sigma(B,C))$ should be always $\sigma(C)$-measurable and this is what you are saying).

Comment: OP: In view of the frantic edits above, I am wondering: do you know the meaning of the expression "to take one's losses"?